# ExtentReport : FreeMarker template error: The following has evaluated to null or missing:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting following exception:

FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> log.stepName  [in template "Extent.Offline.ftl" at line 297, column 93]

---

### Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.

Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if `enter code here`myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:131)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:355)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:268)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    `at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)`
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.HTMLReporter.flush    (HTMLReporter.java:151)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.flush(Report.java:213)
    `at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:491)`
    at com.mobile.app.sainity.testcases.Sainity.main(Sainity.java:147)
`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.utils.Writer.write(Writer.java:21)`
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.HTMLReporter.flush(HTMLReporter.java:164)
    `at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.flush(Report.java:213)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:491)`
    at com.mobile.app.sainity.testcases.Sainity.main(Sainity.java:147)

Comment: can you also paste the relevant code thats causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to latest extent 2.40 version. It works fine for me for offline report.